# Access Trinket m0 USB through GPIO pins

Tags: usb, gpio

I want to solder a USB A connector to my Trinket m0 instead of using an adaptor cable to plug into my PC.

**Can I access Trinket m0 USB through GPIO pins?**

I have looked at the description of the pinouts, but I cannot work out if it is a yes or no.

Any ideas?

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense.  The trinket has a USB connector, that is where you should connect to.

Answer (score 1):

Lucky for you, Adafruit shares the schematics and layout for all their boards. The Trinket M0 schematic is here https://learn.adafruit.com/assets/45723 . Copied for reference:
[image]

As you can see, no, the USB doesn't connect to any of the breakout pins. It goes straight into the microcontroller.